# Count ForEach returns incorrect results

Tags: reporting, business-objects

I have a large dataset which is listing jobs by property. It looks along the lines of this:

Property ID | Job ID
----------- | -----
1 | 10
1 | 11
2 | 12
3 | 13
3 | 14

What I want is the following:

Property ID | Number of Job IDs
1 | 2
2 | 1
3 | 2

I've used the following formula, but it's presenting only 1 or 0, and it appears that it's presenting 1 where there are no jobs, and 0 where there are one or more jobs.

```
=Count([Job ID] ForEach([Property ID])) In([Property ID])
```

A couple of things to consider:

1) I don't have access to edit the Universe
2) I've literally been using BO for 3 weeks...

Can anyone provide the correct variable formula please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=Count([Job ID])
```

should do it, but you may get different results based on the other objects in the block.  If you don't get the expected results try:

```
=Count([Job ID];All)
```

Comment: I'm not blocking the report in any way... I need it to be in one block for export purposes. This is why the ForEach is necessary

Comment: "Block" refers to the visual table in WebI that the objects are in.  So your block has at least two objects (Job ID and Property ID).  Do you have others, particularly dimensions?  That can cause different results.  What do you get from `=count([Job ID])`

Comment: Sorry, thought you meant for each block if I'd split it for Property ID etc. That's worked now. No idea what I had done to it initially to not count that way... might have been over-complicating things!